Solving Max-Cut exactly using SCIP
I have a somewhat sparse graph of 256 nodes with rational weighted undirected edges that I want to find the best possible cut for. It is very important for me that I find the theoretical optimal solution, and not just something that is almost optimal.
My plan was to use https://github.com/scipopt/scip/tree/exact-rational to solve it exactly.
I've tried describing the Max-Cut instance in the following two ways:

As a quadratic objective function with Boolean variables.
Have a [0,1] varible z for every edge (u,v), and bound z by z <= var_u + var_v and z <= 2 - (var_u + var_v). Here var_u and var_v are Boolean variables corresponding to which side of the cut u and v are on.

However, turns out that (1) is not supported by the exact version of SCIP (I get an error message on read), and (2) seems to get stuck with 0.93% gap.
My question: Is there some alternative here? Or is an exact solution of Max-Cut too much to ask for?
Notably, when I tried (1) in Gurobi, it solves the instance almost instantly (<< 1s) even at extreme precision/tolerance settings. So I'm pretty sure I already know the optimal solution.
